# Eigen types typedef failing with C4430

Tags: c++, typedef, eigen

In an academic project I'm trying to setup a simple physics engine.
I am using Eigen library for vector/matrixes calculation.
I'd like to stay as much independent as I can from library/design choices I'm making, to ease future changes, so I'm using typedefs for the Eigen types.

File PhysicsEngine.h

```
#pragma once

#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Geometry>
#include "RigidBody.h"

... other inclusions ...

namespace PhysicsEngine
{
    typedef float real;
    typedef Eigen::Vector3f vector3;
    typedef Eigen::Quaternionf quaternion;
    typedef Eigen::Matrix4f matrix4;
    typedef Eigen::Matrix3f matrix3;

    ...
```

1) Is that a good design choice or am I misunderstanding what my teacher told us?

Including the file above, in RigidBody.h, and trying to use those typedefs:

```
#pragma once

#include "PhysicsEngine.h"

namespace PhysicsEngine
{
    class RigidBody
    {
    public:
    vector3 position;               // <- error C4430
    real inverseMass;               // <- error C4430
    vector3 velocity;               // <- error C4430
    vector3 netForce;               // <- error C4430

    quaternion orientation;         // <- error C4430
    matrix3 inverseInertiaTensor;   // <- error C4430
    vector3 rotation;               // <- error C4430
    vector3 netTorque;              // <- error C4430

    matrix4 transformationMatrix;   // <- error C4430
    ...
```

I get:

> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int.

2) What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that a good design choice or am I misunderstanding what my teacher told us?

It might be a poor design choice since you hide the fact that you are using Eigen types, nevertheless you will need to know this fact in order to use your typedefs.

> I get a lot of errors C4430.

Descriptions like that really annoy me.  Your compiler won't just die with "error C4430", it gives you detailed error information that is crucial for finding the cause of the problem.  You are making it hard for anyone to help you by not sharing this information.  Can you please post the *first complete* message, along with the code line that is causing the error?

The number of errors is irrelevant, since it is probable that most of the errors originate from the same problem.

Since Microsofts *warning* C4430 reads "missing type specifier - int assumed", I suspect that you are forgetting to include Eigen header files, so that the compiler does not know what an `Eigen::Vector2f` is.

Try to add `#include <Eigen/Core>` to `PhysicsEngine.h`.

---

From your updated code: You have circular dependencies.  `PhysicsEngine.h` includes `RigidBody.h` and vice versa.  This is not good.

I suspect that while compiling `RigidBody.cpp`, the compiler will end up parsing the class definition in `RigidBody.h` before the typedefs in `PhysicsEngine.h`, so that your custom typedefs are not available at that point.

You should probably remove the `RigidBody.h` include from `PhysicsEngine.h`, or move your typedefs to a separate header file.

Comment: I did not add the rest of the error because my Visual Studio version is in italian, and i thought C4430 was enough for you to understand the problem. Sorry to have caused you annoyance, i'm now editing my post with the message translation.

Comment: Sorry again, i did not post all the includes. I did it now. Btw all is working correctly without the typedefs, using Eigen types.

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia: The compiler should still give you the file name and line number where the error occurred, can you please post the code at that place, too?

Comment: I do not have the code right here at the moment, but if I remember correctly the error occured on each of the member declarations in class RigidBody in file RigidBody.h (except the one using "real"), I'll check that and update the post asap.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that a good design choice or am I misunderstanding what my teacher told us?

I think you'll get **a lot** of different opinions about this. In my point of view it's not a really good choice (with some exceptions). I try to explain why.

- You will have to write a **lot of code** (maybe one `typedef` for each type in the library).
- Even if you abstract use of `vector3` from real type (`Eigen::Matrix3f`) you **do not get a true independence** because (with the exception of *math* operators) you'll use functions with prototypes defined in that library (think, for example, how the identity matrix is defined in Eigen and in Boost).
- To use a specific math library is **not a micro-design choice**, it pervades all your code, you can't think to be independent with few `typedef`. What next step will be? Wrap all classes to allow dependency injection? If it's what you need maybe you should start with a library designed in that way (but I don't think it's common or even a good idea for a mathematical library).
- You **hide important** *details*. I understand you do not want to propagate if your floating point number is single or double precision but it's important! Rounding errors and precision are *details* you must take care of when you write your code. `typedef` shouldn't be used (but it's my opinion) to abstract your code or to hide implementation details. I think it should be used only as **shortcut** for a long type definition or to switch between two or more **equivalent** definitions. `float` and `double` aren't equivalent (and you  have to always think what you're doing with them). To switch between them can change application results then it's good you can't do it with a small change in your `typedef`.

> What am I doing wrong here?

C4430 error comes when you do not specify the return type of a function (prior to VS2k5 the default was `int` as in C). You can get that error if you declare a variable of an unknown type. In your case you included your header file but maybe it doesn't include the *Global matrix typedefs* from Eigen library (it's in the `Core` header file of the library).

**Edited**: you include `RigidBody.h` in your `PhysicsEngine.h` and vice-versa, fix it (extract your `typedef`, if you want to use them) to another header file and avoid this round-trips.

Comment: I agree on your first three points. As to the last, with modern IDEs a simple F12 would unreveal the typedef of "real" so I think it's not really "hiding" details. That said, I can't use float or real independently from the Matrix types i choose, so using explicit Eigen types will lead me to use explicit float or double too I suppose.

Comment: As I said I guess this topic is perfect for a holy war! :) Even a method implementation is always easy to check, when even a simple assignment operation can lead to a subtle bug then I prefer to catch at _first sight_ what I'm doing in my code. I think typedef should not be used to hide the implementation but only to provide a **shortcut** for a long declaration.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but even if I can't achieve independence from Eigen, I could at least have independence from a specific Eigen type, for example I could switch between Eigen::Matrix3f and Eigen::Matrix3d.

Comment: Yes, that's the point more or less. But I think you should **not** be independent from the floating point precision. Think about this: why they didn't provide a typedef for **Matrix** based on a define like we're used with strings (LPTSTR, LPSTR, LPWSTR...)?

Comment: Thank you, very useful suggestions, the problem was the circular include indeed, Ferdinand pointed it out first so I accepted his answer.